# Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<(null)>. Actual:<System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on unit testing on asp.net mvc3. When I run the test method on a defaultly created test:

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void IndexTest()
        {
            ConferenceController target = new ConferenceController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            ActionResult expected = Index; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            ActionResult actual;
            actual = target.Index();
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
        }
```

This error occurs `[TestMethod()]`:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<(null)>. Actual:.

How to pass the assert?

Answer (score 2):

```
ActionResult expected = Index; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
```

As the comment indicates you should initialize the `Index` variable to an appropriate value. Example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index()
{
    // Arrange
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();

    // Act
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!", result.ViewBag.Message);
}
```

Comment: just read this summary of unit test method , solution above given didn't work /// <summary> ///A test for Index ///</summary> // TODO: Ensure that the UrlToTest attribute specifies a URL to an ASP.NET page (for example, // http://.../Default.aspx). This is necessary for the unit test to be executed on the web server, // whether you are testing a page, web service, or a WCF service.   after implementing above error now comes.......????????????